# Unable to Install Python Package in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, conda

I've just got a new Mac (my first one) and need to install all of my python packages. I've downloaded and installed Anaconda and I'm using the Anaconda Navigator. When I select the package to install (GeoPandas) and click "Apply" all I get is a popup box that says, "The following packages will be modified:" and a "solving package specifications" progress indicator. I've left it running for quite a while and nothing changes. See screenshot below.

What am I doing wrong? How do I install packages using Anaconda Navigator?
[image: navigator]

Comment: Does this happen with other packages or just `geopandas`? i.e. can you install `pandas`? Conda can be notoriously slow at times, although that shouldn't happen with a new computer and a popular package(s).

Comment: Try: ' conda install geopandas' and wait for completion.  About 3 or 4 minutes.